# Social Networking buttons in a list of teasers generated using views

Tags: views, social-network

I have generated a list of blogs with title and teaser , with a pager also , using views. I need to display social buttons like share on Facebook, twitter etc on each items of the list. How can this be implemented?

Comment: I've already done this way: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35211/adding-of-social-media-links-facebook-google-plus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the [ShareThis](https://www.drupal.org/project/sharethis) module. This does what you need.

Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Integration with the [ShareThis](http://sharethis.com/) social bookmarking utility on selected node types.
>
> The code for this project was based on the original [share](https://www.drupal.org/project/share) project for Drupal 5.x. The code for this project has been trimmed down to only work with the ShareThis system, and not require any additional modules to work properly.