# Adding of social media links( Facebook, Google Plus)

Tags: 6, social-network

In [my site](http://www.indiaconsumercomplaints.org) I've already added [Facebook Like](http://drupal.org/project/fblikebutton), [Google Plus](http://drupal.org/project/google_plusone) and [Addthis](http://drupal.org/project/addthis) modules.

Facebook like shows up only in the bottom of the article and it won't display if we're in the home page where no node is shown in full view.

Google Plus also won't show for home page in teaser mode

Addthis shows up in the bottom.

So I've gone ahead and copy pasted this code in the "content top" position in Acquia theme from Addthis.com account:

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="medium"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4ed5fa1d3aa24279"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

So this will make the buttons display on all url's. I just want to know if I'm doing the right way. When I added this same code to another site using Acquia theme in the same position then this code caused the buttons to show in staircase way. So I removed this code.

My main concern is that this code should not break layout in any browser/version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe should you try [ServiceLinks](http://drupal.org/project/service_links/), instead. Very straightforward to implement.

My two cents.

Comment: I've made default install and selected all node types but still I see no links on my pages and site.

Comment: Make sure you also enable a module containing services - then: http://servicelinks.altervista.org/?q=about/configuration